# Replace rare values in a column produces inconsistent result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to replace rare values in a column with 'other-1', 'other-2', etc. based upon the frequency with which the value appears in the column.

I am getting results I can't understand.

```
print((df3['ward'].value_counts() == 1).sum())
```

Yields: 30

```
print((df3['ward'].value_counts() == 2).sum())
```

Yields: 59

```
print((df3['ward'].value_counts() < 3).sum())
```

Yields: 89

OK.  So far all is good.

Now I want to replace those items with 'other-1' and 'other-2', respectively.

```
df3['ward'] = df3['ward'].mask(df3['ward'].map(df3['ward'].value_counts()) == 1, 'other-1')
print((df3['ward'] == 'other-1').sum())
```

Yields 30.  Exactly as expected.

But...

```
df3['ward'] = df3['ward'].mask(df3['ward'].map(df3['ward'].value_counts()) == 2, 'other-2')
print((df3['ward'] == 'other-2').sum())
```

Yields 118.

WHAT?!

That's exactly double the expected value of 59.

And I did check. There zero existing 'other-x' values in the column.

Why isn't the count of 'other-2' == 59?

EDIT.

Just tried using percentages.  Got the exact same result.

```
df3['ward'] = df3['ward'].mask(df3['ward'].map(df3['ward'].value_counts(normalize=True)) < 0.00002, 'other-1')
df3['ward'] = df3['ward'].mask(df3['ward'].map(df3['ward'].value_counts(normalize=True)) < 0.00004, 'other-2')
```

Sample of the data. I tried to put the whole column in but it is too large.

```
'Mundindi', 'Natta', 'Ngorika', 'Nanyumbu', 'Nyakasimbi', 'Moa', 'Samuye', 'Chambo', 'Itetemia', 'Kaisho', 'Tambani', 'Msindo', 'Busilili', 'Siha Kaskazini', 'Nkoma', 'Mkowe', 'Mdandu', 'Usuka', 'Ilangala', 'Mawengi', 'Matola', 'Ikungulyabashashi', 'Usuka', 'Kisiwani', 'Mkigo', 'Kimochi', 'Rutamba', 'Nyaishozi', 'Mengwe Manda', 'Siha Kati', 'Dabalo', 'Chalinze', 'Kilema  Kati', 'Lupanga', 'Baleni', 'Oltrumet', 'Katumbasongwe', 'Mnenia', "Boma la ng'ombe", 'Rugongowe', 'Kahe', 'Ipelele', 'Mtwango', 'Merya', 'Nduruma', 'Samuye', 'Sindano', 'Kiwira', "Boma la ng'ombe", 'Wangama', 'Msaranga', 'Laela', 'Makwale', "Nyang'hwale", 'Kiruruma', 'Njoro', 'Kurua Vunjo Mashariki', 'Oltroto', 'Bargish', 'Izimbya', 'Kicheba', 'Hemtoye', 'Kagongo', 'Kikatiti', 'Nduguti', 'Naintiri', 'Ikuka', 'Isingiro', 'Ilembula', 'Mkigo', 'Utengule', 'Mawindi', 'Ubaruku', 'Manchira', 'Kitagata', 'Kibeta', 'Imalinyi', 'Mbuguni', 'Mashewa', 'Ushirika', "Mang'oto", 'Tawa', 'Nkoanrua', 'Mondo', 'Buswahili', 'Bupandwamhela', 'Magulilwa', 'Kasharunga', 'Chalinze', 'Chihanga', 'Mwamgongo', 'Luchelegwa', 'Kiromo', 'Measkron', 'Kyaka', 'Nyamnyusi', 'Muyama', 'Misasi', 'Mpitimbi', 'Mwantini', 'Mabokweni', 'Ibaga', 'Bunyambo', 'Marumba', 'Masama Mashariki', 'Jipe', 'Isanga', 'Bwanga', 'Kiwere', 'Lutebe', 'Maji ya Chai', 'Maji ya Chai', 'Lusahunga', 'Ndola', 'Kimagai', 'Kashenye', 'Mzumbe', 'Igundu', 'Natta', 'Lengatei', 'Lupalilo', 'Kaibanja', 'Runazi', 'Namanga', 'Itete', 'Urambo', 'Ikungu', 'Imalinyi', 'Jana', 'Usagara', 'Buziku', 'Nduruma', 'Utengule Usangu', 'Ukune', 'Mbaramo', 'Madope', 'Ndalambo', 'Nachunyu', 'Kalenge', 'Nyamigogo', 'Kyela Urban', 'Mkambalani', 'Igigwa', 'Mvomero', 'Kiroka', 'Kitunda', 'Ruhanga', 'Mahongole', "Ng'apa", 'Rujewa', 'Sirari', 'Igurusi', 'Kimbiji', 'Kebanchabancha', 'Muhinda', 'Muhuwesi', 'Igale', 'Masumbwe', 'Ipililo', 'Mchinga', 'Mahongole', 'Miangalua', "Wanging'ombe", 'Ruhita', 'Nyanguge', 'Makuru', 'Nkinga', 'Mganza', 'Chinamili', 'Sindano', 'Mkongo', 'Mtowisa', 'Lugoba', 'Ifakara', 'Kidete', 'Msanzi', 'Magara', 'Bunamhala', 'Iyula', 'Magila', 'Mseke', 'Kilindoni', 'Ngarenanyuki', 'Miangalua', 'Kirongwe', 'Ukumbi', 'Mbangala', 'Kassambya', 'Ilungu', 'Igurusi', 'Siuyu', 'Nyololo', 'Isalavanu', 'Chalinze', 'Mdandu', 'Njengwa', 'Suji', 'Kitirima Kingachi', 'Neruma', 'Mwamashele', 'Nyakisasa', 'Mudida', 'Ikuka', 'Mahongole', 'Mugoma', 'Nyanga', 'Msia', 'Akheri', 'Chalinze', 'Mbulumbulu', 'Ilembula', 'Mwaya', 'Mishamo', 'Ndola', 'Mwembe', 'Bujonde', 'Mabogini', 'Itwangi', 'Olkokola', 'Ruanda', 'Merya', 'Kirangare', 'Kikatiti', 'Munzenze', 'Kibaha', 'Igundu', 'Chakwale', 'Mandewa', 'Masumbwe', 'Mbarika', 'Msambiazi', 'Mukituntu', 'Maghojea', 'Nanguruwe', 'Hidet', 'Iwindi', 'Miguwa', 'Hembeti', 'Kanga', 'Pongwe', 'Rubeho', 'Kigongo', 'Mbalawala', 'Mtimbwani', 'Mahuninga', 'Bukembe', 'Kihorogota', 'Nkumba', 'Kirua Vunjo Magharibi', 'Magawa', "Wanging'ombe", 'Lukulendi', 'Mwika Kusini', 'Malili', 'Ipepo', 'Nyandekwa', 'Kalangalala', 'Kitere', 'Mseke', 'Namanyere', 'Kyaka', 'Chikuyu', 'Mbabala', 'Imesela', 'Zanka', 'Nkoanrua', 'Msambara', 'Ruvu', 'Iwindi', 'Lukulendi', 'Ilima', 'Sikonge', 'Nambinzo', 'Didia', 'Rugongowe', 'Lipingo', 'Mtimbira', 'Duga', 'Kirongwe', 'Chala', 'Munyegera', 'Kibondo Urban', 'Mwamashele', 'Murieti', 'Uvinza', 'Shigala', 'Okoani Kibosho', 'Dakama', 'Ntendo', 'Gwanumpu', 'Mzinga', 'Mwanga', 'Ngarenanyuki', 'Rhotia', 'Mbokomu', 'Chihanga', 'Mkoreha', 'Bwisya', 'Nkangamo', 'Maratani', 'Kirushya', 'Kalangalala', 'Ilola', 'Ikolo', 'Nkinga', 'Buseresere', 'Kasamwa', 'Kisondela', 'Ufana', 'Kiegeani', 'Msindo', 'Inyala', 'Ikolo', 'Isingiro', 'Marumbo', 'Mabamba', 'Mambwenkoswe', 'Ziwani', 'Kicheba', 'Ubaruku', 'Magengeni', 'Zagayu', 'Chunyu', 'Nkungulu', 'Masoko', 'Sintali', 'Kalangalala', 'Mwandiga', 'Mtipwili', 'Hombolo', 'Kiangara', 'Usuka', 'Mbebe', 'Bugoro', 'Mpindo', 'Nandembo', 'Babayu', 'Wangama', 'Kiberege', 'Katazi', 'Mwashiku', 'Isongo', 'Sagara', 'Moivo', 'Endasak', 'Marangu Mashariki', 'Chinamili', 'Ngarenanyuki', 'Liuli', 'Kidugalo', 'Njengwa', 'Mererani', 'Rujewa', 'Rusesa', 'Ihanja', 'Mbugani', 'Bwawani', 'Karambi', 'Ilungu', 'Tingatinga', 'Kongwa Urban', 'Sunya', 'Lupila', 'Choma', 'Ruhita', 'Kidatu', 'USA River', 'Kibara', 'Isikizya', 'Lumemo', 'Kalangalala', 'Mbulumbulu', 'Idete', 'Gumbiro', 'Usuka', 'Chumbi', 'Mchoteka', 'Manchali', 'Marumba', 'Pandambili', 'Kileo', 'Uru Kusini Mawela', 'Qurus', 'Mhunze', 'Usangule', 'Kilagano', 'Mafyeko', 'Mogwa', 'Oljoro', 'Mawengi', 'Ngulla', 'Legezamwendo', 'Mdandu', 'Kitunda', 'Marangu Mashariki', 'Chome', 'Nyololo', 'Maputi', 'Ligera', 'Mkambalani', 'Lemasule', 'Maroroni', 'Muriti', 'Ipande', 'Misasi', 'Mwendakulima', 'Shishiyu', 'Kalenga', 'Doma', 'Mchesi', 'Kirando', 'Idunda', 'Ulaya', 'Nyakahura', 'Lembeni', 'Lupanga', 'Nyanzenda', 'Msongola', 'Kilosa', 'Mabwerebwere', 'Kirua Vunjo Kusini', 'Siha Kati', 'Tumbi', 'Rujewa', 'Kibiti', 'Uru Kaskazini', 'Selela', 'Buhendangabo', 'Msongola', 'Mshewe', 'Kindi', 'Didia', 'Mamire', 'Mwaubingi', 'Kiwira', 'Mabogini', 'Kimnyaki', 'Ibadakuli', 'Mahege', 'Kitobo', 'Mbaya', 'Mbekenyera', "Mang'ula", 'Malangali', 'Chita', 'Masoko', 'Ihango', 'Maligisu', 'Matendo', 'Lufilyo', 'Mnyawa', 'Mbangala', 'Mdandu', 'Kikwe', 'Ngofila', 'Napacho', 'Kibaoni', 'Mdandu', 'Nambilanje', 'Usanda', 'Suji', 'Kiwangwa', 'Kikomero', 'Muhange', 'Olele', 'Nainokanoka', 'Kidodoma', 'Msindo', 'Barikiwa', 'Mgambo', 'Rangwi', 'Mtapenda', 'Samuye', 'Minepa', 'Nyakisasa', 'Uwemba', 'Ikwiriri', 'Murieti', 'Olele', 'Mgungira', 'Ketumbeine', 'Salawe', 'Uvinza', 'Kiranyi', 'Mtitaa', 'Vikindu', 'Kiranyi', 'Mamboya', 'Siha Magharibi', 'Kifanya', 'Jangwani', 'Ushirika', 'Buyango', 'Mgombasi', 'Shagihilu', 'Namwinyu', 'Suji', 'Nyololo', 'Nanjota', 'Zinga/Ikerege', 'Lupembe', 'Kibaoni', 'Badi', 'Pemba Mnazi', 'Keni Mengeni', 'Murungu', 'Komuge', 'Bwawani', 'Muze', 'Kiranyi', 'Namatutwe', 'Murufiti', 'Kahororo', 'Mbulumbulu', 'Mshewe', 'Bushiri', 'Mtinko', 'Akheri', 'Imesela', 'Shume', 'Machame Magharibi', 'Nkungulu', 'Ikuka', 'Lemasule', 'Kolandoto', 'Mshewe', 'Ufukoni', 'Kwai', 'Matimba', 'Izazi', 'Didia', 'Euga', 'Kiromo', 'Gua', 'Selambala', 'Mawindi', 'Gendabi', 'Mzumbe', 'Ulenje', 'Mlimba', 'Visiga', 'Ulenje', 'Isange', 'Ifunda', 'Lupalilo', 'Keni Mengeni', 'Bashinet', 'Mahenge', 'Mikalanga', 'Usangule', 'Namanyere', 'Ntuntu', 'Irole', 'Mdandu', 'Lukulendi', 'Kitunda', 'Chimala', 'Visiga', 'Bukome', 'Mahanje', 'Madibira', 'Kisiju', 'Mabwerebwere', 'Mamsera', 'Ikuka', 'Njoge', 'Mwangaza', 'Kitunda', 'Lufilyo', 'Msindo', 'Namalenga', 'Usanda', 'Mwandoya', 'Kagongo', 'Soga', 'Kigonsera', 'Panzuo', 'Madilu', 'Msanga', 'Rangwi', 'Ikindwa', 'Msisi', 'Msimbu', 'Myovizi', 'Fukalo', 'Bunyambo', 'Ntendo', 'Maore', 'Nala', 'Nduruma', 'Ilangala', 'Kidodi', 'Muriba', 'Kihurio', 'Kiomboi', 'Kimagai', 'Kagongo', 'Msisi', 'Mdandu', 'Jamhuri', 'Mwamalili', 'Kintinku', 'Manchali', 'Mwakilyambiti', 'Bukene', 'Kate', 'Makata', 'Msanzi', 'Segera', 'Ruanda', 'Igurusi', 'Mbuguni', 'Itilima', 'Miguwa', 'Nyakasasa', 'Siuyu', 'Komuge', 'Kifanya', 'Shume', 'Kafunzo', 'Mazinde', 'Mawengi', 'Miono', 'Ipililo', 'Vikindu', 'Kihonda', 'Nditi', 'Kahororo', 'Masuguru', 'Kicheba', 'Idahina', 'Masange', 'Ngongowele', 'Nangowe', 'Kate', 'Mamba Kusini', 'Somangira', 'Magawa', 'Ligunga', 'Mbokomu', 'Ruhita', 'Kitulo', 'Uru Kusini Mawela', 'Likawage', 'Magomeni', 'Kisiwani', 'Dunda', 'Makwale', 'Mvumi Mission', 'Mkamba', "Mang'ula", 'Mshewa', 'Mbuga', 'Janda', 'Munyegera', 'Mandawa', 'Mogwa', 'Lembeni', 'Kigonsera', 'Mhango', 'Mangirikiti', 'Kidatu', 'Sudi', 'Magagura', "King'ori", 'Ruhembe', 'Itwangi', 'Maligisu', 'Nanga', 'Dindira', 'Mchombe', 'Myunga', 'Kileo', 'Lupanga', 'Songa', 'Namabengo', 'Imalinyi', 'Kikatiti', 'Nyaluhande', 'Rungemba', 'Kabaragaine', 'Namatutwe', 'Lugoba', 'Tinde', 'Kigondo', 'Kurui', 'Kyerwa', 'Budekwa', 'Liuli', 'Ngimu', 'Isagehe', 'Masange', 'Masange', 'Ushirombo', 'Chimala', 'Kenyamonta', 'Mkwaja', 'Ikungulyabashashi', 'Utengule', 'Lupalilo', 'Mwamala', 'Nyambureti', 'Pugu', 'Mlangarini', 'Mfumbi', 'Mwabuma', 'Ligera', 'Katoro', 'Mwandoya', 'Ruaha', 'Masaki', 'Nkumba', 'Nandembo', 'Butiama', 'Nyamirembe', 'Mwaniko', 'Uru Mashariki', 'Kolandoto', 'Narungombe', 'Kurua Vunjo Mashariki', 'Nyakabindi', 'Diongoya', 'Kalulu', 'Ntobo', 'Mondo', 'Nyimbili', 'Machame Kaskazini', 'Rau', 'Ikoma', 'Usuka', 'Lukulendi', 'Mchombe', 'Mwabusalu', 'Dutwa', 'Nduguti', 'Mahurunga', 'Kinaga', 'Kahamanhalaga', 'Milola', 'Mphwayungu', 'Bugene', 'Chitete', 'Hedaru', 'Matola', 'Kakola', 'Mpui', 'Ufukoni', 'Mtwango', 'Kwai', 'Kindi', 'Yombo', 'Kimuli', 'Endasak', 'Kabita', 'Dihimba', 'Nkololo', 'Mchauru', 'Bashay', 'Namajani', 'Mpindo', 'Usagara', 'Murieti', 'Idete', 'Mpui', 'Lagangabilili', 'Kidodi', 'Maweni', 'Mlimba', 'Sunga', 'Makuyuni', 'Maghojea', 'Rubale', 'Ifakara', 'Namabengo', 'Luchingu', 'Rujewa', 'Koromije', 'Mgori', 'Mtumba', 'Mchinga', 'Farkwa', 'Mwandoya', 'Mlunduzi', 'Kibosho Kati', 'Mchukwi', 'Tinde', "Ring'wani", 'Inyala', 'Hunyari', 'Tungamaa', 'Maji ya Chai', 'Budakwa', 'Usuka', 'Image', 'Shinghatini', 'Mhunze', 'Muungano', 'Chanika', 'Gamboshi', 'Bugarama', 'Mzenga', 'Kijungu', 'Katwe', 'Muhuwesi', 'Malinyi', 'Mamboya', 'USA River', 'Rungwe Mpya', 'Ikuka', 'Mkoma', 'Chiwonga', 'Mnero Miembeni', 'Ilolo Mpya', 'Missungwi', 'Lupiro', 'Kidugalo', 'Mima', 'Lupembe', 'Mgambo', 'Mvuha', 'Maramba', 'Kiegei', 'Rubeho', 'Kitirima Kingachi', 'Isingiro', 'Kihorogota', 'Kifanya', 'Kitongo Sima', 'Berege', 'Ikungu', 'Igosi', 'Mbangamao', 'Ubaruku', 'Mamba', 'USA River', 'Kimochi', 'Ubangaa', 'Malindi', 'Pandagichiza', 'Nyakabindi', 'Mji Mwema', 'Kabungu', 'Nyabusozi', 'Mbwewe', 'Mererani', 'Ushirika', 'Mtambula', 'Masange', 'Mpuguso', 'Mbweni', 'Namanyere', 'Mbuga', 'Bushiri', 'Lulindi', 'Igalula', 'Kazunzu', 'Kiberege', 'Kitunda', 'Irole', 'Buterankuzi', 'Pangani Mashariki', 'Nshamba', 'Milogodi', 'Mishamo', 'Buhingo', 'Masuguru', 'Rubeho', 'Balangidalalu', 'Bwambo', 'Vikindu', 'Ubiri', 'Machame Uroki', 'Ikondo', 'Mikunguni', 'Bumilayinga', 'Mninga', 'Ruhembe', 'Ikondo', 'Kigondo', 'Kirushya', 'Yombo', 'Machame Kaskazini', 'Siha Kati', 'Ruaha', 'Soga', 'Lunguya', 'Chanzuru', 'Mwanjoro', 'Matola', 'Nanjota', 'Puma', 'Kwai', 'Ikindwa', 'Mwamalole', 'Luchelegwa', 'Gode Gode', "Mang'ula", 'Soga', 'Masama Magharibi', 'Moshono', 'Kalulu', 'Sandulula', 'Bugarama', 'Mbinga Urban', 'Suji', 'Endasak', 'Inyonga', 'Mtibwa', 'Ruhunga', 'Kiloli', 'Kidegembye', 'Chinamili', 'Kidatu', 'Akheri', 'Lukulendi', 'Kibirizi', 'Magubike', 'Rungwe Mpya', 'Mogwa', 'Nyamoko', 'Namwinyu', 'Lwangwa', 'Makuro', 'Nyanzenda', 'Kiromo', 'Bumilayinga', 'Solwa', 'Ludewa', 'Ruiwa', 'Nshamba', 'Visiga', 'Mnyuzi', 'Sunga', 'Ihanda', 'Matola', 'Nduruma', 'Mdandu', 'Lusewa', 'Karatu', 'Mwaswale', 'Bunda', 'Lubugo', 'Mwika Kaskazini', 'Bashinet', 'Bushiri', 'Hai Urban', 'Ngongwa', 'Igosi', 'Songosongo', 'Mbezi', 'Mvomero', 'Mogitu', 'Madanga', 'Isongole', 'Kalenge', 'Didia', 'Isanga', 'Mombo', 'Lupembe', 'Msindo', 'Somanda', 'Ngudu', 'Mkowe', 'Nkumba', 'Ihanda', 'Katoro', 'Sejeli', 'Naumbu', 'Namasakata', 'Soga', 'Ihanda', 'Lugulu', 'Monduli Juu', 'Kihanga', 'Iyogela', 'Mtitu', 'Dumila', 'Ruhita', 'Kirua Vunjo Magharibi', 'Mkomazi', 'Kyela Urban', 'Kidatu', 'Kisangura', 'Oltrumet', 'Ihembe', 'Masela', 'Msindo', 'Muriaza', 'Ludewa', 'Njoge', 'Kagongo', 'Kikatiti', 'Bunamhala', 'Oltroto', 'Soera', 'Kisegese', 'Kilelema', 'Iwindi', "Mang'ula", 'Kibaha', 'Munyegera', 'Lusu', 'Mpitimbi', 'Mpunze', 'Kebanchabancha', 'Makwale', 'Ligunga', 'Mlangali', 'Ukune', 'Ntuntu', 'Lufilyo', 'Kibiti', 'Mbangala', 'Nondwa', 'Kibedya', 'Igongolo', 'Kibaoni', 'Namatutwe', 'Mbaramo', 'Bugarama', 'Ikhawoda', 'Ushirombo', 'Dabil', 'Keni Mengeni', 'Chokaa', 'Katwe', 'Nyamato', 'Nkumba', 'Bugarama', 'Masange', 'Kwakoa', 'Matai', 'Bugorora', 'Buhanda businde', 'Kilema  Kati', 'Marangu Mashariki', 'Sakasaka', 'Chiponda', 'Kigongo', 'Kilindoni', 'Kunduchi', 'Lupalilo', 'Maposeni', 'Chala', 'Kitunda', 'Minepa', 'Irole', 'Lembeni', 'Mninga', 'Ilongero', 'Kipanga', 'Tai', 'Matema', 'Mawindi', 'Nkololo', 'Kanazi', 'Mdandu', 'Miteja', 'Kileo', 'Marangu Magharibi', 'Kimanzichana', 'Itete', 'Manda', 'Lusewa', 'Mishamo', 'Kisongo', 'Yaeda Chini', 'Maghang', 'Pugu', 'Lipumburu', 'Chanika', 'Karitu', 'Kidodi', 'Mtimbira', 'Igalla', 'Ngarenanyuki', 'Mzizima', 'Malenga Makali', 'Bugarama', 'Kalemela', 'Kidatu', 'Mkwamba', 'Zanka', 'Liuli', 'Kashasha', 'Mipingo', 'Sadani', 'Magoma', 'Malinyi', 'Namanyere', 'Imalinyi', 'Chumo', 'Kalinzi', 'Marumbo', 'Biirabo', 'Msia', 'Diongoya', 'Chunyu', 'Mkomazi', 'Kahe Mashariki', 'Ikuka', 'Muhange', 'Kongolo', 'Keni Mengeni', 'Sumve', 'Chabutwa', 'Mwaya', 'Uvinza', 'Mwandu', 'Nyamigogo', 'Muganza', "Boma la ng'ombe", 'Kitagata', 'Hungumalwa', 'Igongolo', 'Riroda', 'Mwangaza', 'Ipililo', 'Nyigogo', 'Busi', 'Nishambya', 'Kiwira', 'Kalangalala', 'Mtina', 'Buganguzi', 'Mavanga', 'Upuge', 'Nyamigogo', 'Ruiwa', 'Namikango', 'Potwe', 'Lembeni', 'Measkron', 'Sangabuye', 'Mahongole', 'Ilongero', 'Mbogwe', 'Mahida Holili', 'Munyegera', 'Malolo', "Ng'hundi", 'Bugarama', 'Chunyu', 'Nambambo', 'Ifakara', 'Lunguya', 'Kagongo', 'Utete', 'Makuro', 'Mkalamo', 'Sunya', 'Nkwenda', 'Utengule Usongwe', 'Ikondo', 'Mwamgongo', 'Maramba', 'Chiugutwa', 'Magengati', 'Buhendangabo', 'Ilolangulu', 'Uwemba', 'Mkambalani', 'Kigongo', 'Nambinzo', 'Bwiro', 'Isalavanu', 'Kirua Vunjo Kusini', 'Nkwenda', 'Sakwe', 'Ibadakuli', 'Lilambo', 'Samuye', 'Lupalilo', 'Upuge', 'Mwika Kusini', 'Msata', 'Mwankoko', 'Igosi', 'Nduruma', 'Pande', 'Nyankanga', 'Bugarama', 'Mangirikiti', 'Usagara', 'Miono', 'Mkigo', 'Kishapu', 'Kiwira', 'Igalula', 'Chilangala', 'Sumve', 'Busolwa', 'Njoro', 'Kisale Msangara', 'Natta', 'Nyarero', 'Marui', 'Kiva', 'Magomeni', 'Sindeni', 'Machame Kaskazini', 'Igale', 'Nainokanoka', 'Luponde', 'Bungu', 'Mazwi', 'Mima', 'Mahida Holili', 'Kasoli', 'Rwinga', 'Mundindi', 'Maramba', 'Kisondela', 'Litembo', 'Mkowe', 'Maputi', 'Mgwashi', 'Kabita', 'Upuge', 'Nambinzo', 'Nakatuguru', 'Murangi', 'Matiri', 'Bukumbi', 'Kigondo', 'Binagi', 'Kalambazite', 'Rusumo', 'Bujonde', 'Melela', 'Mlangali', 'Mamba Kusini', 'Bukombe', 'Olkokola', 'Maji ya Chai', 'Malolo', 'Hogoro', 'Nanyumbu', "Ilkiding'a", 'Mishamo', 'Somanda', 'Magoma', 'Msindo', 'Igurusi', 'Kasungamile', 'Mukituntu', 'Mwika Kusini', 'Rujewa', 'Mwantini', 'Mpepai', 'Lubanga', 'Masumbwe', 'Nyakabindi', 'Kisesa', 'Madunga', 'Badi', 'Rusumo', 'Kalinzi', 'Tumati', 'Shelui', 'Kiwalala', 'Mamba Kusini', 'Mpinji', 'Nala', 'Bugarama', 'Ushirika', 'Orkesumet', 'Usuka', 'Makwale', 'Kipande', 'Ihanda', 'Imalinyi', 'Mkoreha', 'Mamboya', 'Luagala', 'Katangara Mrere', 'Gelai Meirugoi', 'Itigi', 'Njoro', 'Kamachumu', 'Nyamoko', 'Mererani', 'Kimochi', 'Kisemu', 'Bulongwa', 'Kasanga', 'Kimnyaki', 'Shambarai', 'Igongolo', 'Siha Kaskazini', 'Masama Mashariki', 'Nkoma', 'Kulimi', 'Mpanda Ndogo', 'Kisorya', 'Namtuhuka', 'Ihowanza', 'Kicheba', 'Unyambwa', 'Kwamatuku', 'Kilimatinde', 'Gungu', 'Merya', 'Mkula', 'Kibaoni', 'Kisongo', 'Lupanga', 'Magomeni', 'Rusesa', 'Lugoba', 'Mahurunga', 'Ilela', 'Maji ya Chai', 'Potwe', 'Kidatu', 'Bonde la Songwe', 'Tingi', 'Buswelu', 'Kirwa Keni', 'Mtanana', 'Bugarama', 'Usagara', 'Mwagi', 'Mtanila', 'Kiranyi', 'Utete', 'Kibengu', 'Hedaru', 'Kibingo', 'Kwamsisi', 'Matai', 'Rusesa', 'Maramba', 'Nkoma', 'Somanda', 'Lufingo', 'Mkuyuni', 'Mbaya', "Munga'a", 'Kimamba B', 'Ndumbwe', 'Mondo', 'Mahanje', 'Kasokola', 'Mkata', 'Olkokola', 'Nyarubungo', 'Ngerengere', 'Igalula', 'Kadoto', 'Mwimbi', 'Ipala', 'Maore', 'Issenye', 'Iduo', 'Kurua Vunjo Mashariki', 'Siha Kati', 'Didia', 'Ikuka', 'Mwandeti', 'Pemba Mnazi', 'Chibe', 'Choma', 'Kebanchabancha', 'Igowole', 'Kikatiti', 'Imalinyi', 'Mahembe', 'Sofi', 'Tabaruka', 'Kirushya', 'Muzye', 'Nyamuswa', 'Marangu Magharibi', 'Mdandu', 'Isansa', 'Bitale', 'Nkwenda', 'Kidodi', 'Igongolo', "Munga'a", 'Igosi', 'Mwika Kusini', 'Magugu', 'Mahuta', 'Vikindu', 'Namasakata', 'Utengule Usangu', 'Maposeni', 'Senga', 'Dareda', 'Dihimba', 'Chitete', 'Maratani', 'Chunyu', 'Simbo', 'Kahama Urban', 'Ifakara', 'Sejeli', 'Mnekachi', 'Inyonga', 'Maji ya Chai', 'Rulenge', 'Mengwe Manda', 'Uru Kusini Mawela', 'Nkungulu', 'Nandembo', 'Liwale A', 'Lake Jipe', 'Huzi', 'Oltroto', 'Biro', 'Matimira', 'Bupigu', 'Kibaoni', 'Kasanda', 'Shume', 'Iduo', 'Mingumbi', 'Mudida', 'Lusahunga', 'Bargish', 'Msingi', 'Rubale', "Nyang'hwale", 'Mogitu', 'Olkokola', 'Murutunguru', 'Kiruruma', 'Katuma', 'Masuguru', 'Magara', 'Kibara', 'Lutebe', 'Luegu', 'Mtina', 'Bugarama', 'Kwai', 'Mkwamba', 'Kinyeto', 'Chanika', 'Kashishi', 'Yombo', 'Kiloleli', 'Katwe', 'Itaka', 'Budekwa', 'Namajani', 'Lupila', 'Lugulu', 'Itewe', 'Ruanda', 'Nyaishozi', 'Kibamba', 'Mwaswale', 'Ngimu', 'Kisongo', 'Gisambalang', 'Kachwamba', 'Maruku', 'Kolero', 'Tuwemacho', 'Bukombe', 'Nyamalimbe', 'Suji', 'Ipepo', 'Kirwa Keni', 'Itete', 'Lukanga', 'Isagehe', 'Mamsera', 'Mvomero', 'Monduli Juu', 'Kabanga', 'Kitama', 'Luegu', 'Shinghatini', 'Ughandi', 'Ushirika', 'Arusha Chini', 'Gwandi', 'Misasi', 'Kiromo', 'Ntobeye', 'Kisaki', 'Mdandu', 'Kiromo', 'Kyimo', 'Kirua Vunjo Kusini', 'Uwemba', 'Kimamba B', 'Mnero Ngongo', 'Sukuma', 'Mamsera', 'Lupembe', 'Kileo', 'Kirua Vunjo Magharibi', 'Buruma', 'Kabungu', 'Kiruruma', 'Mlambo-Itobo', 'Rubeho', 'Igalukilo', 'Talaga', 'Marumbo', 'Pito', 'Kanyangereko', 'Olgosorok', 'Nyakasimbi', 'Nyamoko', 'Nanjara Reha', 'Utengule Usongwe', 'Ipepo', 'Mnyuzi', 'Mseke', 'Ntwike', 'Ipala', 'Kitagata', 'Dongobesh', 'Mkalamo', 'Ngoma', 'Utengule Usongwe', 'Bunju', 'Kibakwe', 'Kinyeto', 'Bumera', 'Irole', 'Kiranyi', 'Lupembe', 'Mazinde', 'Lupata', 'Kamuli', 'Suji', 'Kibosho Kati', 'Laela', 'Paranga', 'Arash', 'Kigondo', 'Mwandoya', 'Liuli', 'Kukirango', 'Masama Mashariki', 'Unyamikumbi', 'Kilosa Mpepo', 'Mbuyuni', 'Bukombe', 'Kijungu', 'Tingi', 'Maratani', 'Mwingiro', 'Endulen', "Ilkiding'a", 'Kibaoni', 'Murieti', 'Makwale', 'Mbokomu', 'Marui', 'Ruanda', 'Matendo', 'Chanika', 'Matiri', "Nyang'hwale", 'Usuka', 'Olkokola', 'Lubugo', 'Kisuke', 'Naberera', 'Mingumbi', 'Lupalilo', 'Bulungwa', 'Ruaruke', 'Ikungulyabashashi', 'Lupata', 'Ndolwa', 'Songwa', 'Mazinde', 'Mikangaula', 'Mahembe', 'Msia', 'Kisemu', 'Oltrumet', 'Kiomboi', 'Songambele', 'Mtitaa', 'Kipanga', 'Chalinze', 'Machame Mashariki', 'Kyimo', 'Kiwira', 'Chipanga', 'Dareda', 'Mishamo', 'Singisi', 'Nyabubinza', 'Ilembula', 'Katuma', 'Itigi', 'Arusha Chini', 'Ilolangulu', 'Nyamhula', 'Kalangalala', 'Busilili', 'Bugene', 'Mamboya', 'Lukulendi', 'Lukokoda', 'Gamboshi', 'Njengwa', 'Wasa', 'Kirua Vunjo Magharibi', 'Gare', 'Mwadobana', 'Mwandiga', 'Mamboya', 'Chiola', 'Nyamtukuza', 'Magugu', 'Imalinyi', 'Mwandiga', 'Busangi', 'Mtae', 'Kicheba', 'Ushirombo', 'Ushirika', 'Kisese', 'Songoro', 'Ikolo', 'Kibiti', 'Murutunguru', 'Mukituntu', "Boma la ng'ombe", 'Kerenge', 'Nyanzenda', 'Iragua', 'Bushiri', 'Luhunga', 'Kitanda', 'Igosi', 'Kilimatinde', 'Matekwe', 'Mnyamba', 'Namatutwe', 'Nyamilama', 'Ndungu', 'Ikunguigazi', 'Lingeka', 'Nzuguni', 'Nyabibuye', 'Ubiri', 'Oldonyosambu', 'Kikatiti', 'Mwimbi', 'Chumo', 'Malangali', 'Zanka', 'Shelui', 'Mtwango', 'Kitunda', 'Kirongwe', 'Nata', 'Ihanja', 'Dakama', 'Mpui', 'Igongwa', 'Muungano', 'Lyenje', 'Lagangabilili', 'Machame Magharibi', 'Mvomero', 'Nkololo', 'Masagati', 'Vudee', 'Mwamishali', 'Nyambono', 'Mombo', 'Somangira', 'Kimamba A', "Wanging'ombe", 'Lagangabilili', 'Tinde', 'Tumbi', 'Diongoya', 'Mtimbira', 'Marambo', 'Bunamhala', 'Chipanga', 'Mapogoro', 'Iguguno', 'Mikumi', 'Nyimbili', 'Sali', 'Nzihi', 'Chawi', 'Makukwe', 'Kidodi', 'Makiidi', "Wanging'ombe", 'Moshono', 'Kasharu', 'Bumera', 'Riroda', 'Chikuyu', 'Mtoa', 'Utete', 'Maji ya Chai', 'Mishamo', 'Dabil', 'Singisi', 'Buchambi', 'Kajunjumele', 'Mwika Kusini', 'Kibutuka', 'Mdandu', 'Namajani', 'Munyegera', 'Machame Kaskazini', 'Magomeni', 'Kisegese', 'Chita', 'Kirando', 'Issenye', 'Nyambiti', 'Ilunda', 'Chiwezi', 'Bombo', 'Mapogoro', 'Utete', 'Kanyangereko', 'Mambali', 'Sopa', 'Nsimbo', 'Liuli', 'Lumuli', 'Nanjara Reha', 'Mapogoro', 'Chimala', 'Ilolangulu', 'Magu Urban', 'Lagangabilili', 'Ruhunga', 'Kirua Vunjo Kusini', 'Kanyenye', 'Zombo', 'Lembeni', 'Shimbi', 'Kitulo', 'Lilambo', 'Nguvu Moja', 'Mwaya', 'Kebanchabancha', 'Mabamba', 'Idodi', 'Soga', 'Kiwira', 'Lusungo', 'Kyerwa', 'Mdandu', 'Mnima', 'Kitere', 'Sanje', 'Mwanhunzi', 'Sanu', 'Nyakonga', 'Magole', 'Nyabibuye', 'Kilimani', 'Ihanda', 'Malindi', 'Mungumaji', 'Msata', 'Wotta', 'Iniho', 'Makote', 'Masange', 'Kibengu', 'Ushirombo', 'Vikindu', 'Sungaji', 'Ukiriguru', 'Kwaluguru', 'Masama Mashariki', 'Kisegese', 'Simbo', 'Rwabere', 'Bweranyange', 'Sikonge', 'Kigunga', 'Lukulendi', 'Ntobo', 'Kwai', 'Sumve', 'Mabamba', 'Masagalu', 'Bwambo', 'Mabamba', 'Chumo', 'Pangani Mashariki', 'Msangano', 'Hungumalwa', 'Moivo', 'Busagara', 'Kyimo', 'Chibe', 'Lupalilo', 'Ngarenanyuki', 'Masama Magharibi', 'Milola', 'Mazwi', 'Kate', 'Moa', 'Busolwa', 'Murufiti', 'Kanga', 'Sikonge', 'Rungwe Mpya', 'Mombo', 'Ipande', 'Kyimo', 'Maramba', 'Maposeni', 'Ulenje', 'Ikama', 'Mpuguso', 'Ngarenanyuki', 'Nduruma', 'Yombo', 'Ikhawoda', 'Kenyamonta', 'Nduguti', 'Ikinga', 'Kalangalala', 'Mpuguso', 'Masama Kusini', 'Igongolo', 'Kahe', 'Zinga/Ikerege', 'Kisanga', 'Busi', 'Vibaoni', 'Mtumba', 'Machame Kaskazini', 'Bubiki', 'Mkalamo', 'Wangama', 'Chiwonga', 'Kibeta', 'Mingumbi', 'Sakwe', 'Mpunguzi', 'Natta', 'Mwamalole', 'Kilimani', 'Merya', 'Luchelegwa', 'Ubaruku', 'Kimochi', 'Lusungo', 'Pandambili', 'Kalenge', 'Mbesa', 'Dabaga', 'Ikola', 'Mkongo', 'Ruanda', 'Igurusi', 'Mlunduzi', 'Maji ya Chai', 'Levolosi', 'Kitunda', 'Mwabuma', 'Koryo', 'Sakasaka', 'Ntobeye', 'Kalangalala', 'Mengwe Manda', 'Mtinko', 'Igosi', 'Maore', 'Nduruma', 'Chanzuru', 'Mtinko', 'Kelamfua Mokala', 'Nyakasasa', 'Matekwe', 'Rujewa', 'Tembela', 'Sepuko', 'Lusanga', 'Kabasa', 'Zinga/Ikerege', 'Magole', 'Namwinyu', 'Songosongo', 'Shambarai', 'Luponde', 'Kalinzi', 'Natta', 'Leguruki', 'Kizumbi', 'Kingale', 'Kitongo Sima', 'Chanika', 'Ilangala', 'Kilagano', 'Kileo', 'Nyakitonto', "Wanging'ombe", 'Igoweko', 'Nyamidaho', 'Bulongwa', 'Lupila', 'Matendo', 'Mlimba', 'Marangu Magharibi', 'Mima', 'Rubeho', 'Misezero', 'Mpotwa', 'Nzera', 'Mhinduro', 'Nyamatare', 'Chunyu', "Ilkiding'a", 'Matamba', 'Namalenga', 'Kifanya', 'Kisongo', 'Hedaru', 'Merya', 'Luegu', 'Kasamwa', 'Dindira', 'Mbuzii', 'Sanje', 'Kirua Vunjo Kusini', 'Ipole', 'Bukoli', 'Mwamapalala', 'Mawindi', 'Biharamulo Urban', 'Nduruma', 'Lushoto', 'Mishamo', 'Sanje', 'Missungwi', 'Arusha Chini', 'Kibakwe', "Dung'unyi", 'Lundi', 'Kikunde', 'Kandete', 'Mkalamo', 'Masuguru', 'Kambasegese', 'Igurusi', 'Wotta', 'Lemasule', 'Kirwa Keni', 'Njombe Urban', 'Mwamabanza', 'Mgandu', 'Masumbwe', 'Mingumbi', 'Makwale', 'Ikindwa', 'Kipanga', 'Ikungulyabashashi', 'Makuyuni', 'Muyama', 'Nkoma', 'Kazazi', 'Same Urban', 'Ifakara', 'Zombo', 'Ipepo', 'Malolo', 'Mwaru', 'Unyambwa', 'Mishamo', 'Masela', 'Mbuzii', "Mang'oto", 'Kiranjeranje', "Ng'hundi", 'Endabash', 'Kwamtoro', 'Mashewa', 'Moshono', "Mang'ula", 'Mwamapalala', 'Mantare', 'Pahi', 'Luhundwa', 'Ikunguigazi', 'Pangani Mashariki', 'Kikatiti', 'Nyamimange', 'Katumbasongwe', 'Bumbuta', 'Simbo', 'Mangirikiti', 'Mwadobana', 'Kirangare', 'Kakonko', 'Ulenje', 'Iyula', 'Kibosho Magharibi', 'Maligisu', 'Mwada', 'Murungu', 'Mpanda Ndogo', 'Kijungu', 'Lumemo', 'Dumila', 'Keni Mengeni', 'Sungaji', 'Mgori', 'Makwale', 'Iyula', 'Kigonsera', 'Ipera', 'Iponya', 'Kilimatinde', 'Mwembe', 'Measkron', 'Kolero', 'Mogitu', 'Mubunda', 'Igosi', 'Utengule Usangu', 'Bendera', 'Chalinze', 'Nyamimange', 'Mwananyili', 'Lutale', 'Maghang', 'Ngerengere', 'Kilema Kusini', 'Mahembe', 'Malinyi', 'Misha', 'Rujewa', 'Rabuor', 'Igamba', 'Kipatimu', 'Bumilayinga', 'Hombolo', 'Chambo', 'Murufiti', 'Mwamgongo', 'Funta', 'Leguruki', 'Munyegera', 'Kihurio', 'Leguruki', 'Bassotu', 'Minepa', 'Muhinda', 'Nkoma', 'Usangule', 'Mapogoro', 'Maramba', 'Nkoma', 'Kahe', 'Nyamtukuza', 'Malindi', 'Mvomero', 'Pasua', 'Nyigogo', 'Kigonsera', 'Akheri', 'Nkinga', 'Oldonyosambu', 'Uru Shimbwe', 'Oljoro', 'Mkonze', 'Nduruma', 'Kindi', 'Mwakanshashala', 'Wotta', 'Ngokolo', 'Nyabusozi'
```

Comment: It's the Taarifa water challenge dataframe from DrivenData.  I am working on the 'ward' column.

Comment: I added some of the column data.  I tried to add in the whole column but it is too large.